# Tableau: add 3 different paths (Bar, lines and dotted) lines in one visual

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api

I have a question about Tableau and I was hopping to get some help here.

Goal:
Visualize 3 different paths(bars, line and dotted line) in one visual.

What I have done:
To visualize two paths(bars and line) in one visual I have used Dual Axis which works well. Problem is that now, one if the lines we have I would like to show it as a dotted line, but if I change one, it seems that all the other lines are changed to the same path. Would you know how to tackle this this challenge?
Adding screenshot for more clarification.
Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: As of now tableau has not given the functionality for editing line types.  As far as I know

Comment: Yes..only using trend lines which is not idea... thanks!